# Execution time of properties checking

Tags: nusmv

I want to know how to calculate the execution time of CTL/LTL properties  checking in NuSMV model checker.

...
thanks

> Blockquote

....

```
....
```

Comment: I think the best way to achieve this is to fork the source code of NuSMV and add the necessary timing code.

Comment: You have said "timing code" ,Please, is there any command in NuSMV that calculates execution time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the command `print_usage`. However, this might not be **that much** precise if your purpose is to collect timing statistics for some scientific purpose.

**Example:**

```
NuSMV > reset
NuSMV > read_model -i some_model.smv
NuSMV > go                                                                                  
NuSMV > print_usage                                                                         
...
User time    0.268 seconds
System time  0.043 seconds
...

NuSMV > check_property                                                                      
-- specification AG (AF state = MOVE)  is false
-- as demonstrated by the following execution sequence
...

NuSMV > print_usage   
...
User time    0.494 seconds
System time  0.051 seconds
...

NuSMV > quit
```

The difference between the final time and the starting time provides a rough measurement of the time required for checking the property.

---

In practice, the approach described in this answer may not be quite effective for automated tasks requiring some degree of precision. Luckily, the **source code** of `NuSMV` is publicly available, so you can actually modify it so that it computes the exact time taken by each property being checked. This may require some `c++` development skills.